# tabela de abreviações de 3 letras para cidades por estado

Tags: string, português-do-brasil, algoritmo-fonético

No Estado de SP por exemplo `ADA` seria Adamantina, `ADO` Adolfo, `AGU` Aguai, `AGD` Agudos, ..., `ADC`,  Alvaro de Carvalho, `ABR` Americo Brasiliense, ... `SJC` Sao Jose dos Campos, ... Mas "poderia ser" é chute.

As três letras constarão em meio físico (placas) e digital, não podem ser arbitrárias.  Precisamos de preferência de um padrão, como fez a IATA (aeroportos) ou Anatel, mas não um padrão federal (*namespace* de ~5500 itens para as 3 letrinhas), um padrão estadual, onde por exemplo em SP temos ~650 itens para associar os códigos das mesmas 3 letras.

### NOTA TÉCNICA

O código de 3 letras faz o papel de um código de *hash*, e neste sentido vale a [relação clássica de chance de colisão](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Generalizations)... Se temos 26^3 combinações com 3 letras, para manter em níveis aceitáveis as chances de colisão, não podemos mapear mais do que uma fração disso, digamos 1% a 5% das 17576 combinações. O *namespace* de 5500 (31%!) justamente extrapolou e a Anatel pagou o preço, foi forçada a usar Y no lugar de I,  ou "abreviações nada-haver" por conta do excesso de colisões nas escolhas mais mnemônicas — mais parecem placas de carro do que siglas mnemônicas. 
Da minha avaliação os 3% de SP ou max. 4% de MG são razoáveis e gerariam bons resultados.

---

Se houver um algoritmo pronto e padronizado seria também uma solução. Por exemplo Metaphone é um padrão mas não preserva o mesmo alfabeto nem gera códigos mnemônicos para iniciais no caso de nomes compostos (ex. São José dos Campos resultaria em SJC) de duas ou mais palavras. Acredito que não precisemos "reinventar a roda" e o algoritmo ideal para o português já exista... Grosseiramente o algoritmo ideal é simples, faz isso:

1. Se nome simples, tenta as 3 primeiras letras. 
   *Itu* e *Jaú* ficam resolvidos automaticamente, *Campinas* e *Marília* ficariam  `CAM` e `MAR`.

   1.1. Se houver colisão (ex. *Marinópolis* não pode usar `MAR`), adotar a primeira letra seguida de apenas consoantes (ex. `MRN`).
2. Nomes compostos de várias palavras: tentar primeiro as iniciais sem preposiçao, depois gerar combinações com o item anterior das palavras inicial ou final do nome.
    Exemplo: *Santa Rita do Passa Quatro* pode ser `SRP`, `SPQ`, ... ou ainda `STQ`, `SQT`, etc.

Ideal que o algoritmo seja bem fundamentado e já adotado como padrão em outro lugar.

Outro problema a ser resolvido pelo algoritmo, para que seja justo com os futuros usuários das siglas criadas. Quem merece mais a sigla "mais bonita"?  
Por exemplo, `BOR` vai para Borborema (15790 habitantes e fundada em ) ou para Borá (890 habitantes e fundada em 1965 )?  A mais antiga ou a mais populosa?

---

### Referências

- Cidades brasileiras com aeroportos: aparentemente todas elas deveriam ter abreviações IATA, mas não encontrei uma listagem sistemática do Brasil (não confundir com [aeroportos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digos_IATA_de_aeroportos_brasileiros))... Alguns exemplos mas não sei se são oficiais: `ANS` Anápolis-GO, `PTM` Patos de Minas-MG, `PTS` Patos-PB,  `URA` Uberaba-MG, `UDI` Uberlândia-MG... e os mais exóticos,  `BSB` Brasília-DF, `GYN`  Goiânia-GO, ...
- Abreviações Anatel: só em [PDF](http://portal.embratel.com.br/fazum21/pdf/codigos_ddd.pdf) e parece ser (*Date  HTTP header*) de 2013.
- Abreviações do CDHU/SP: não possuem 3 letras, mas são todas palavras simples e reduzidas, simplificando bastante o trabalho do algoritmo. Ajudaria como "referência oficial" se não houver outra de ponto de partida... Só está disponível em [PDF](http://www.cdhu.sp.gov.br/download/manuais-e-cadernos/nomenclatura/nomenclatura-municipios.pdf) e parece ser  de 2005.
- Dados das cidades, por estado, etc. [Wikidata](http://wikidata.org.br). Como fazer [queries SparQL](https://query.wikidata.org) pode ser chato, algumas tabelas como a [de São Paulo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_munic%C3%ADpios_de_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_por_popula%C3%A7%C3%A3o)  já se encontram prontas, e um [dataset homologado](https://github.com/datasets-br/city-codes) também pode ser utilizado.

Comment: Que tal pegar o da Anatel e separar por estado?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado editei a questão explicando melhor, confira a "NOTA TECNICA", se precisar reviso.

Comment: @Bacco, agradeço por estar explicando seu voto-contra, mas repare que estou apenas contextualizando o problema, não me importo se responderem com C# ou Perl ou etc... E justamente um problema que fiz questão de trazer aqui e não no Stackoverflow principal, porque quero primeiro enfatizar o contexto da lingua portuguesa (!).  São questões numéricas, posso remover tudo que coloquei sobre Brasil e SP, mas perderia o contexto... Que tal esperar a comunidade se manifestar? Já haviam 2 votos creio que em 1 semana alguém responde... Ou acha mais importante dar mais cara de "problema de programação"?

Comment: Meu voto não é vinculante, teria que ter mais 4 de fechamento. Pode ser que o pessoal não feche. Eu até acho que foi bem elaborada, mas não consigo ver problema real de programação que não deixasse no mínimo ampla. A necessidade em si eu acho realmente fora de escopo (mas é como eu vejo, não necessariamente como outros vêem).

Comment: De qualquer forma, retirei o comentário e o voto pra não influenciar, e logo mais deleto estes aqui.

Comment: @PeterKrauss se eu entendi bem você quer um algorítimo que que defina um código de 3 letras para cada município do Brasil? 
Temos 5564 municípios( segundo fonte: https://ww2.ibge.gov.br/home/estatistica/populacao/contagem2007/popmunic2007layoutTCU14112007.xls ) e 17576 combinações possíveis!
Acho que consigo fazer em Python + SQLite!

Comment: Eu inicialmente achei que o @Bacco estava sendo ortodoxo demais em relação ao escopo. Porque a pergunta é interessante, e mesmo que rigorosamente fora do escopo pensei que talvez desse pra encaixar forçando a barra um pouco. Vendo como a pergunta evoluiu, pensei até em fechar como não clara ou mesmo "baseada em opiniões" também. Resolvi ficar com a sugestão do Bacco porque no fundo é pergunta pra um geógrafo responder.

Comment: Oi @DiogoLindoso, o que tentei expressar é que as abreviações para os ~5600 municípios já existem, foram feitas pela Anatel, e que não queremos isso ("... mas não um padrão federal"), estamos buscando abreviações por conjuntos menores, por estado: SP, MG, etc. que nunca passam dos ~800. Quanto ao algoritmo que esbocei é um chute, é bacana fazer mas o difícil mesmo é descobrir se existe algum "algoritmo padrão", que já venha sendo usado ou tenha uma boa fundamentação.

Comment: Caso não exista um padrão (e a sua pesquisa prévia parece indicar isso), qualquer caminho será arbitrário. Você está em busca do menos arbitrário possível, certo? "Possível" dentro de condições que você mesmo está determinando. Precisaria definir mais claramente as condições. Por exemplo, a população deve ser levada em conta? A resposta que apareceu desconsiderou isso. As regras sobre colisões não estão claras também. Pode repetir siglas em estados diferentes? Definidas as condições, o algoritmo estaria praticamente dado. Nesse caso, o que sobraria pra perguntar?

Comment: Bom, já respondeu uma das minhas pergunta no comentário postado quase ao mesmo tempo do meu. :) Reitero que acho o assunto interessante, mas não sei como deixar a pergunta menos problemática.

Comment: @bfavaretto, sim, nos faltam parâmetros e fundamentos, não sei se edito mais uma vez a pergunta ou se começo um Github ;-) Como já começaram a responder vou fazer uns testes e manter também uma certa compatibilidade entre pergunta e resposta.. A resposta parece boa, talvez fiquemos por aqui.

Comment: teve progresso @PeterKrauss ?

Comment: Oi @RovannLinhalis, estou aguardando sinal verde de um projeto para retomar o assunto aqui, com subsídios no Github... Na verdade um algoritmo quebra-galho, como o da resposta atual (que foi ótima!), eu já havia publicado em PHP antes de vir fazer a pergunta... O projeto não visa o CEP mas pode ser melhor entendido/imaginado como substituto do CEP numérico por um código com letras e números, iniciado pelas 2 letras do estado, depois 3 letras do município. Ver https://github.com/OSMBrasil/CRP  e  http://datasets.ok.org.br/city-codes

Answer (score 4):

De forma oficial, também procurei e não encontrei nada a respeito, acredito que se houvesse, estaria no IBGE.

A solução poderia ser um algoritmo próprio, e claro, manter armazenados esses registros para caso haja uma nova cidade no estado, o resultado seja igual.

---

**C**om um pouco de tempo e vários `for`s, fiz esse algoritmo para gerar as siglas, não levei em consideração a UF, e a ordenação das cidades é alfabética.

**B**asicamente a prioridade é que a primeira letra seja a inicial da primeira palavra. A segunda letra, a inicial da segunda palavra. A terceira Letra, a inicial da última palavra.

Não sendo possível, tenta pegar as letras seguintes, das palavras seguintes ou anteriores (no caso da última letra).

Não sendo possível, tenta pegar a 2 letras seguintes da primeira palavra, e se também não for possível, percorre a primeira palavra de forma reversa tentando montar a sigla.

Se depois de todas as tentativas, não for possível, a flag de sucesso continua como false e o sistema avisa que não gerou sigla para aquela palavra.

Segue o código comentado:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> cidades = new List<string>(645);
    #region addCidades
    cidades.Add("BIRITIBA-MIRIM");
    cidades.Add("BOA ESPERANCA DO SUL");
    cidades.Add("CONCHAL");
    cidades.Add("DOBRADA");
    cidades.Add("DOIS CORREGOS");
    cidades.Add("MERIDIANO");
    cidades.Add("MESOPOLIS");
    cidades.Add("MIGUELOPOLIS");
    cidades.Add("MINEIROS DO TIETE");
    cidades.Add("MIRA ESTRELA");
    cidades.Add("MIRACATU");
    cidades.Add("MIRANDOPOLIS");
    cidades.Add("NOVA CAMPINA");
    cidades.Add("PANORAMA");
    cidades.Add("VIRADOURO");
    cidades.Add("VISTA ALEGRE DO ALTO");
    cidades.Add("VITORIA BRASIL");
    cidades.Add("VOTORANTIM");
    cidades.Add("VOTUPORANGA");
    cidades.Add("ZACARIAS");
    #endregion

    //Primeiro a lista é ordenada por ordem alfabética, fazendo com que a sigla SAL seja gerada para a cidade SALES e não para a cidade SALTO.

    Dictionary<string, string> siglas = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    foreach (string c in cidades)
    {
        string[] cs = c.Replace("'", " ").Replace("-"," ").Split(' '); //Depois, vamos separar cada nome em palavras com o `Split(' ')`, observando que as cidades com hifén ou apóstrofo também são separadas em palavras.
        bool sucesso = false;
        string sigla = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < cs.Length && !sucesso; i++) //Percorrer cada palavra
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cs[i].Length && !sucesso; j++) //Percorrer cada letra da palavra atual (i)
            {
                sigla = cs[i][j].ToString(); //Primeira letra da sigla

                for (int k = i+1; k < cs.Length && !sucesso; k++) //Se há mais palavras depois da palavra atual (i), entra no for
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < cs[k].Length && !sucesso; l++) //Percorre cada letra da palavra (k)
                    {
                        sigla = cs[i][j].ToString() + cs[k][l].ToString(); //Segunda letra da sigla

                        for (int m = cs.Length-1; m > k  && !sucesso; m--) //Se há mais palavras além da palavra (k), entra no for
                        {
                            for (int n = 0; n < cs[m].Length && !sucesso; n++) //Percorre cada letra da palavra (m)
                            {
                                sigla = cs[i][j].ToString() + cs[k][l].ToString() + cs[m][n].ToString(); //Terceira letra da sigla

                                if (!siglas.ContainsKey(sigla)) //Se a sigla ainda não foi utilizada
                                {
                                    siglas.Add(sigla, c); //Adiciona no dicionário
                                    sucesso = true; //Marca a flag como sucesso pra sair de todos os outros for
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        for (int m = l+1; m < cs[k].Length && !sucesso; m++) //Se não gerou a terceira letra com a palavra m, percorre as letras seguintes à (l) da palavra (k)
                        {
                            sigla = cs[i][j].ToString() + cs[k][l].ToString() + cs[k][m].ToString(); //Terceira letra da sigla

                            if (!siglas.ContainsKey(sigla)) //Se a sigla ainda não foi utilizada
                            {
                                siglas.Add(sigla, c); //Adiciona no dicionário
                                sucesso = true; //Marca a flag como sucesso pra sair de todos os outros for
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }


                for (int m = j + 1; m < cs[i].Length && !sucesso; m++) //Se não gerou a segunda letra com a palavra (k) percorre a palavra [i]
                {
                    if (m + 1 < cs[i].Length) //Dá preferência a letra seguinte se existir
                    {
                        sigla = cs[i][j].ToString() + cs[i][m].ToString() + cs[i][m + 1].ToString(); //Compoe a sigla com a segunda (m) e terceira letra (m+1)

                        if (!siglas.ContainsKey(sigla)) //Se a sigla ainda não foi utilizada
                        {
                            siglas.Add(sigla, c); //Adiciona no dicionário
                            sucesso = true; //Marca a flag como sucesso pra sair de todos os outros for
                        }
                    }

                    for (int n = cs[i].Length - 1; n >= 0 && !sucesso; n--) //Percorre a palavra (i) no sentido inverso para gerar a terceira letra
                    {
                        sigla = cs[i][j].ToString() + cs[i][m].ToString() + cs[i][n].ToString(); //Compoe a sigla com a segunda (m) e terceira letra (n)

                        if (!siglas.ContainsKey(sigla)) //Se a sigla ainda não foi utilizada
                        {
                            siglas.Add(sigla, c); //Adiciona no dicionário
                            sucesso = true; //Marca a flag como sucesso pra sair de todos os outros for
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        if (sucesso) //Se foi possível gerar a sigla
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sigla " + sigla + " gerada para a cidade " + c);
        }
        else //Se nenhuma combinação foi possível
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Não foi gerada sigla para a cidade " + c);
        }


    }

    Console.WriteLine("Siglas geradas: " + siglas.Count + " de um total de " + cidades.Count+" cidades");

    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

> Resultado:

```
Sigla BMI gerada para a cidade BIRITIBA-MIRIM
Sigla BES gerada para a cidade BOA ESPERANCA DO SUL
Sigla CON gerada para a cidade CONCHAL
Sigla DOB gerada para a cidade DOBRADA
Sigla DCO gerada para a cidade DOIS CORREGOS
Sigla MER gerada para a cidade MERIDIANO
Sigla MES gerada para a cidade MESOPOLIS
Sigla MIG gerada para a cidade MIGUELOPOLIS
Sigla MDT gerada para a cidade MINEIROS DO TIETE
Sigla MET gerada para a cidade MIRA ESTRELA
Sigla MIR gerada para a cidade MIRACATU
Sigla MIS gerada para a cidade MIRANDOPOLIS
Sigla NCA gerada para a cidade NOVA CAMPINA
Sigla PAN gerada para a cidade PANORAMA
Sigla VIR gerada para a cidade VIRADOURO
Sigla VAA gerada para a cidade VISTA ALEGRE DO ALTO
Sigla VBR gerada para a cidade VITORIA BRASIL
Sigla VOT gerada para a cidade VOTORANTIM
Sigla VOA gerada para a cidade VOTUPORANGA
Sigla ZAC gerada para a cidade ZACARIAS
Siglas geradas: 20 de um total de 20 cidades
```

Coloquei no **[.NETFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8UFnLn)**

> Obs. Pelo comprimento do código, coloquei apenas 20 cidades. No Fiddle tem todas as 645 de SP que eu tinha aqui na base.

---

Extra:

> Gerei as siglas para 2977 cidades que tenho aqui na base e não houve nenhum problema:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Rapaz, impressionante. Tem como compartilhar a ideia por traz de tantos laços?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado tentei passar a ideia na descrição... o que acha ?